# Reading/Writing/Appending using json module

Tags: python, json, file, python-2.7

I was recommended some code from someone here but I still need some help. Here's the code that was recommended:

```
import json
def write_data(data,filename):
    with open(filename,'w') as outfh:
        json.dump(data,outfh)

def read_data(filename):
    with open(filename, 'r') as infh:
        json.load(infh)
```

The writing code works fine, but the reading code doesn't return any strings after inputting the data:

```
read_data('player.txt')
```

Another thing that I'd like to be able to do is  to be able to specify a line to be printed. Something that is also pretty important for this project / exorcise is to be able to append strings into my file. Thanks to anyone that can help me.

Edit: I need to be storing strings in the file that I can convert to values. IE;

```
name="Karatepig"
```

Is something I would store so I can recall the data if I ever need to load a previous set of data or something of that sort.

I'm very much a noob at python so I don't know what would be best, whether a list or dictionary; I haven't really used a dictionary before, and also I have no idea yet as to how I'm going to convert strings into values.

Comment: You do need to assign the result to a variable: `data = readdata('player.txt')`.

Comment: You'll need to show us what data you are writing; is it a dictionary, a list, what is *contained* in the data you are writing and reading?

Comment: Edited. Again, I basically have only like 3 hours of working time in python, so take it easy, heh.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose you have a dictionary like this:

```
data = {'name': 'Karatepig', 'score': 10}
```

Your `write_data` function is fine, but your `read_data` function needs to actually return the data after reading it from the file:

```
def read_data(filename):
    with open(filename, 'r') as infh:
        data = json.load(infh)
    return data

data = read_data('player.json')
```

Now suppose you want to print the name and update the score:

```
print data['name']
data['score'] += 5  # add 5 points to the score
```

You can then write the data back to disk using the `write_data` function.  You can not use the `json` module to append data to a file.  You need to actually read the file, modify the data, and write the file again.  This is not so bad for small amounts of data, but consider using a database for larger projects.

Whether you use a list or dictionary depends on what you're trying to do.  You need to explain what you're trying to accomplish before anyone can recommend an approach.  Dictionaries store values assigned to keys (see above).  Lists are collections of items without keys and are accessed using an index.

It isn't clear what you mean by *"convert strings into values."*  Notice that the above code shows the string "Karatepig" using the dictionary key "name".

Comment: This is exactly what I needed. Thank you so much. There is one issue though; when I read back the data I get this "u" in there. Can that be fixed?

Comment: @Karatepig: That means you have a unicode string. You don't have to worry about that unless you are mixing byte strings (without a `u` prefix) and unicode strings with values outside the ASCII range.

Comment: @Karatepig: If you are interested in the difference, see http://docs.python.org/2/howto/unicode.html. The `json` module returns unicode strings because the JSON standard specifies strings are Unicode, always.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Okay thanks. I'm still learning so really any type of reading helps.